# Proof of, or constraints for, a matrix to be positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have a symmetric matrix whose elements are given by

$$A_{wx} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} {^{wx}\lambda}_i^{2}$$

where ${^{wx}\lambda}_i = {^{xw}\lambda}_i \ge 0$, and ${^{ww}\lambda}_i = 1 \ \forall w,i$.

I might be asking something really trivial here, but is it possible to prove that $\boldsymbol{A}$ is positive semidefinite, or to find conditions for $\boldsymbol{A}$ to be positive semidefinite?

Thanks.

Comment: Your lower bound $^{wx}\lambda_i\geq 0$ doesn't seem relevant if you are going to square it anyway? An upper bound like $^{wx}\lambda_{i}^{2}\leq 1/N$ would do it though.

Comment: Actually $^{wx}\lambda_{i}^{2}\leq 1/(d-1)$ for $d$ dimension of the vector space, since that would imply diagonal dominance.

Comment: @Ali Thanks, diagonal dominance is certainly one condition that I can check (but can't impose due to the physics of the system, unfortunately). But from some of the numerical results I have, diagonal dominance is too strong a condition while the matrix is still positive-semidefinite.